# C# Web API SQL Server 2012: Errors Under Load Test (14 million+ Records)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, load-testing

I am trying to build a Web API that connects to a SQL Server 2012 database with 14 million+ records in a single table. The only action for the API is GET, and will be available to the public as an Open Data API, so it needs to be able to handle many concurrent users.

The table has seven fields:

```
field1 bigint  
field2 nvarchar(50)  
field3 nvarchar(10)  
field4 float  
field5 datetime  
field6 nvarchar(20)  
field7 nvarchar(10)
```

I have written simple test APIs in:
- C# .NET 4.6.1
- C# .NET Core 2

I've also tried ApirIO as a Nuget package, and as a command-line app.

I have also tried using Python Eve with SQLAlchemy but with similar results.

The API works in that I can see the results on my browser, Postman, cURL, etc. But when I try to load test using Vegeta at a rate of 30 requests per second (test duration 30 seconds), I get multiple connection errors and latency rises to around 30 seconds.

I have pasted the results for a load test on the API running on the AperIO command line app:

```
Requests      [total, rate]            900, 30.03
Duration      [total, attack, wait]    59.9700536s, 29.966666367s, 30.003387233s
Latencies     [mean, 50, 95, 99, max]  29.903549803s, 30.002625352s, 30.004389905s, 30.012575115s, 30.03090955s
Bytes In      [total, mean]            49579, 55.09
Bytes Out     [total, mean]            0, 0.00
Success       [ratio]                  1.22%
Status Codes  [code:count]             200:11  0:889  
Error Set:
Get http://localhost:18092/xyz?pageSize=25: net/http: timeout awaiting response headers
```

I have tried C# with and without OData, and with manually coded paging classes with the max page size set to 50, then 25, then 10, then 5, but the results are all broadly similar.

Note: I truncated the table and re-populated with 5000 records and there were no problems with the load test. I re-populated with 14 million records and the errors re-appeared.

Is there some way SQL Server can be optimised to serve a database with a recordset of over 14 million to an API with multiple concurrent users (e.g. 1000 users) with a very low latency (around 0.015sec)?

Thanks in advance,
Mo

#### Edit (to clarify from comments):

The server has RAM 32GB / Memory 160GB / 4 CPUs

- The CPUs went to 100% after about 5 seconds, we temporarily upped the server to 8 CPUs but they also went up to 100%

There is a clustered and non-clustered index on the table

The Linq code for the Get method in the Controller is:

```
var source = (from aqm in _context.aqm_context.
         OrderBy(a => a.field1)
         select aqm).AsQueryable();

var items = source.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList();
return items;
```

From SQL Server Profiler, the SQL being executed is

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[field1] AS [field1], 
    [Extent1].[field2] AS [field2], 
    [Extent1].[field3] AS [field3], 
    [Extent1].[field4] AS [field4], 
    [Extent1].[field5] AS [field5], 
    [Extent1].[field6] AS [field6], 
    [Extent1].[field7] AS [field7]
    FROM [dbo].[table] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[field1] ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

I was originally using MongoDB with [Python Eve](http://python-eve.org/) (with the same recordset) and I was getting 0.015 sec latency with no errors running the same tests. MongoDB is not on my organisation's list of approved technologies (yet) so I was asked to try SQL Server as a backend. I tried the same Eve config using SQLAlchemy connected to SQL Server and immediately received poor latency and connection errors.

So the question could also be:
- Is SQL Server a valid choice to serve an open data API with a recordset of 14 million to the public with potentially thousands of concurrent users? Or is a NoSQL document store like MongoDB better suited?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your table? How much memory is available to SQL Server, what kind of storage & CPUs on it? Are you sure it's SQL Server that's the bottleneck in the first place?

Comment: To add to what @alroc asked; what is your SQL query?  How many rows do you return?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've edited the question  - let me know if you need more detail

Comment: As I read this question it sounds to me like you are expecting to return 14 million rows to 1,000 simultaneous connections and you expect it to be fast. That is 14 billion rows being sent to 1,000 different pipes.

Comment: Well, I'm asking if it's possible. Say if I set maximum results per Get request to 50 (or lower) in C#?

Comment: I was originally using MongoDB + Python Eve with no problems, but was asked to use SQL Server. I'll edit the question to add info about MongoDB

Comment: Looking at your linq - you are selecting the entire 14mil rows? You should have no issues whatsoever if you had paging. We have 10k concurrent users hitting an API which queries db table with 50 mil records with no problems, however, they are querying based on primary key so only 1 result is ever returned.

Comment: Fire up your profiler, intercept an actual query and execute it with execution plan displayed.

Comment: Hi Vidmantas, when I add a limit to the Linq, e.g. select aqm).AsQueryable().Take(100);
I can only page through the first 100 records.

Comment: @Mojo_IRL And that sounds the right way to do it - you never fetch the entire database and store it in memory. When you need to display page 2 - do `Skip((pageNumber - 1) * 100).Take(100)`

Comment: @Vidmantas Blazevicius  I've edited the question to show more of the C# code. I'm already applying Skip and Take by creating an items variable and returning that, i.e. var items = source.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList();
return items;

Comment: Just to share experience here, I've worked on a solution back in 2012 with a dataset consisting of more than 2 Billion rows. We needed <300ms end-to-end response time for fetching individual rows based on indexed (varchar(16)) keys for up to 50k concurrent users. This didn't seem possible at the time, so we ended up sharding the data over 14 different databases of 140mln rows each by picking 1-2 set characters for the key per database. This easily met the performance requirement. I think that goes to show how big the difference is between getting specific indexed keys vs a large set.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, **Can SQL Server handle this amount of data?**

Yes, we are already using it with 400 million rows. Below was steps we followed:

1. We opted for a multi-core server and divided the tempdb there and put on SSD.
2. For us, read operation was important, so indexing was done based on that.
3. We enabled paging via [OFFSET FETCH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx), and made sure we are hitting right indexes.
4. Made it mandatory for only certain amount are allowed to extracted by client applications (not all in one go). Only warehousing applications were allowed, but again during off-peak time aka 2 AM
5. Indexes can do magic, if read operation is priority.
6. Also, we have archiving in place, which moves records older than 2 years into archive tables. This keeps the size of our table almost static.

I thought instead of asking what you are doing, which is not 100% clear, to me, as there are several questions. I thought of sharing how we did to achieve performance. Again, this is not full-proof; however, works for our case. For you, something else might work.